# rename file(s) in folder by list in R

Tags: r

SO!

I am struggling with renaming files in a folder. It is easily done manually with *file.rename*. I wanna do it in another way, though.

Let's say I have two lists:

```
list_correct_names <- list(apples = c("size", "weight"), pears = c("taste","color"))

list_wrong_names <- list(appples = c("size", "weight"), pearrs = c("taste","color"))
```

"appples" and "pearrs" from **list_wrong_names** are the file names in the folder and size/weight/taste/color are the headers. The names of the files are wrong, the headers are correct, though.

**list_correct_names** is a template I create by hand with the names and headers I expect. I want to rename the files in the folder with the names of **list_correct_names** by the matched headers.

The file appples would become apples and the file pearrs would become pears.

For me, the tricky thing is, that it should apply for any kind of list with the corresponding "template" (list_correct_names). It's not always lists of fruits, sometimes it's vegetables. Or it's not 2 files, but 3.

Any hint is appreciated.

EDIT:

These could serve as the files in the folder:

```
appples <- tibble("size" = c(1,2,3), "weight" = c(1,2,3))
pearrs <- tibble("taste" = c(1,2,3), "color" = c(1,2,3))
```

Comment: The question you are putting forward is interesting. However, I think it needs a little bit more details. Can you please provide a reproducible example, i.e. the input and the expected output? Ideally, your example includes the variablity you have.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I don't quite understand, though. The ouput are the changed names and the input is the two lists. Can you go into more detail of what information you need?

Comment: appples <- tibble("size" = c(1,2,3), "weight" = c(1,2,3)) ... pearrs <- tibble("taste" = c(1,2,3), "color" = c(1,2,3)) ... these could be the two files in the folder.

Comment: A list of input file names, and a list of expected output file names would be nice, e.g. Of course, it should be obvious which input file names map to which output file names.

Comment: Is my edit what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's one approach:

```
replacement <- names(list_wrong_names)
names(replacement) <- names(list_wrong_names)

for (wn in names(list_wrong_names)){
  w_cont <- list_wrong_names[[wn]]
  for (cn in names(list_correct_names)){
    c_cont <- list_correct_names[[cn]]
    if (identical(w_cont, c_cont)) 
      replacement[[wn]] <- cn
  }
}


file.rename(names(replacement), replacement)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#list with wrong names
list <- list(appples = c("size", "weight"), pearrs = c("taste","color"))

#Correct names
names(list) <- c("apples","pears")
```

Or maybe this:

```
#list with wrong names
list <- list(appples = c("size", "weight"), pearrs = c("taste","color"))

#Correct a specific name
names(list)[names(list)=="appples"] <- c("apples")
```

Comment: Hi Marcos, thanks for your reply. Sadly this doesn't answer my question. I don't want to change the names of the files in R, but in the folder. Also, one code only should be applicable to many files with the corresponding template.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I imagine the scenario looks like. I’m using csv files here,
modify accordingly for the file format you have.

```r
# Set up files with wrong file names
wrong_files <- list(
  pearrs = data.frame("taste" = c(1, 2, 3), "color" = c(1, 2, 3)),
  appples = data.frame("size" = c(1, 2, 3), "weight" = c(1, 2, 3))
)

dir <- file.path(tempdir(), "foo")
dir.create(dir)

for (file in names(wrong_files)) {
  write.csv(wrong_files[[file]], file.path(dir, file), row.names = FALSE)
}

list.files(dir)
#> [1] "appples" "pearrs"
```

With the manually created list of expected file names based on column names,
we can use a loop to read the column names from all files in the directory of
interest, and check them against the known good column names, renaming the
file with the good name if they match.

```r
list_correct_names <- list(apples = c("size", "weight"), pears = c("taste", "color"))

files <- list.files(dir, full.names = TRUE)
for (file in files) {
  # If the directory can contain non-csv files, maybe tryCatch here for that
  file_cols <- names(read.csv(file, nrows = 1)) # Read just column names
  for (correct_name in names(list_correct_names)) {
    correct_cols <- list_correct_names[[correct_name]]
    # Choose the criteria for when the names match as you see fit
    if (identical(file_cols, correct_cols)) {
      msg_fmt <- "Column names for '%s' matched the names for '%s'. Renaming."
      message(sprintf(msg_fmt, basename(file), correct_name))
      file.rename(file, file.path(dirname(file), correct_name))
    }
  }
}
#> Column names for 'appples' matched the names for 'apples'. Renaming.
#> Column names for 'pearrs' matched the names for 'pears'. Renaming.

list.files(dir)
#> [1] "apples" "pears"
unlink(dir, recursive = TRUE) # Cleanup
```